# term for white torture

Tags: word-request

Sleep deprivation for days, being kept in isolation for weeks, regular simulated executions - so-called ,,white torture". Is this term correct in English or maybe there is a a better term to use to describe those methods?

Comment: Psychological torture?

Comment: I gave your question a more appropriate tag. However, note that you should "[demonstrate why you expect the word to exist in English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/word-request/info)". (Of course, feel free to use "phrase-request" or another tag if that's what you want.)

Comment: Have you looked up "white torture" in an English dictionary or even via an online search engine?

Comment: And here I was thinking this was gonna be a racial thing :p

Answer (score 2):

Amnesty International define 'torture' this way:

> Torture is when somebody in an official capacity inflicts severe **mental** or **physical** pain or suffering on somebody else for a specific purpose. (*bold added*)

While there might be other classifications, methods of torture can seemingly be classified as either *mental torture* or *physical torture*.

Most of what you describe sounds like it would fall under 'mental' torture, although perhaps there is a fine line when it comes to "simulated" experiences like you mention, as there may be some degree of physical interference with the subject. So-called 'waterboarding', for example, is meant to simulate the feeling of drowning, which must be terrifying mental torture - but it is done through physical means which have proven dangerous to the point of causing death.